# _init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype' in EXPORT

Tags: django, django-admin

I get this error when I try to export data from model through the xadmin pages.

```
Class ModelAdmin(object):
    reversion_enable = True
    list_display = (
    'name', 'description', 'pref_name', 'target_type', 'organism', 'tax_id', 'chembl_id', 'uniprot_accession')
    search_fields = ['name', 'description', 'chembl_id', 'uniprot_accession', 'pref_name']
    style_fields = {'description': "rich-textarea"}
    list_export = ('xls', 'xml', 'json', 'csv')

Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/xadmin/idg/moleculedictionary/?_do_=export&export_type=xls&export_xls_header=on

Django Version: 1.7.8
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('idg',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django_comments',
 'django_countries',
 'xadmin',
 'crispy_forms',
 'reversion',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
(u'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/sites.py" in wrapper
  291.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/sites.py" in inner
  199.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/views/base.py" in view
  256.             return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/views/base.py" in method
  72.             return filter_chain(filters, len(filters) - 1, _inner_method, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/views/base.py" in filter_chain
  41.         return func()
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/views/base.py" in _inner_method
  66.             return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/views/list.py" in get
  412.         response = self.get_response(context, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/views/base.py" in method
  72.             return filter_chain(filters, len(filters) - 1, _inner_method, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/views/base.py" in filter_chain
  55.         return filter_chain(filters, token - 1, _inner_method, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/views/base.py" in filter_chain
  41.         return func()
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/views/base.py" in _inner_method
  54.                 return fm(func if fargs[1] == '__' else func(), *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xadmin/plugins/export.py" in get_response
  218.             mimetype="%s; charset=UTF-8" % self.export_mimes[file_type])
File "/home/idg/.virtualenvs/idg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py" in __init__
  318.         super(HttpResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /xadmin/idg/moleculedictionary/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'
```

I have added the list_export as suggested in the xadmin documents. But not much help.
what am I doing wrong? Any suggestion would be much appreaciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of xadmin that you have installed is not compatible with Django 1.7+ It is using the the `mimetype` argument, which was [removed in Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-7).

The issue has been [fixed in the master branch](https://github.com/sshwsfc/django-xadmin/commit/164f2b9ddb35520097ff8d0df31ec6e3ebaa68ba), but it doesn't look as if there has been a new release since then.

You could try installing the master branch, but I would be wary of using an app that hasn't had a release for so long, unless you're confident debugging issues like this.

Comment: I am using django 1.7.8

Comment: Yes, I can see that from the traceback. As I said, the version of xadmin you are using does not work with Django 1.7 or later.

Comment: pip install git+git://github.com/sshwsfc/django-xadmin.git@164f2b9ddb35520097ff8d0df31ec6e3ebaa68ba This solved this. Thanks